# JavaScript class that generates HTML form with validation

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, dom

I'm trying to create a complex application—Table generator. And the first part if it is form that lets user input data source. As I figure source should be an absolute http url, so I have to give user `<input>` with validation, and `<button>` which will reflect validation state.

Eventually I came up with this:

```
class Form {
  constructor () {
    this.button            = document.createElement('button')
    this.button.innerHTML  = 'Upload'
    // Initially it's empty so it's invalid
    this.button.disabled   = true

    this.input             = document.createElement('input')
    this.input.placeholder = 'Path to data'
    // Let's assign our custom validator
    // since validation props are read only
    this.input.oninput     = () => this.validate()
  }
  validate () {
    // Tribute @LukeP
    // https://stackoverflow.com/a/34695026/2626747
    // Let's use anchor superpowers
    // rather then google `url regex`
    const a = document.createElement('a')
    a.href  = this.input.value
    // If typed value couldn't be parsed as an absolute url,
    // it'd be considerd as a path on current host
    this.button.disabled = !(a.host && a.host != window.location.host)
  }
  render () {
    const form = document.createElement('form')
    form.appendChild(this.input)
    form.appendChild(this.button)
    return form
  }
}

const form = new Form()
document.getElementById('app').appendChild(form.render())
```

I'm not satisfied with this code, and I can not explain why. I don't have somewhat strong experience in JS, so I'm relying on your peer review.

Help me make Web better, starting with my app.

Answer (score 2):

I'd just move the render part to the constructor and provide it with the id of the parent element.

```
class Form {

   constructor( id ) {

      const button = document.createElement('button');
      button.value = "Upload";
      button.disabled = true;

      const input = document.createElement('input');
      input.placeholder = 'Path to data';
      input.oninput = () => this.validate();

      this.input = input;
      this.button = button;

      const form = document.createElement('form');
      form.appendChild(input);
      form.appendChild(button);
      document.getElementById(id).appendChild(form);

   }

   validate () {

      const a = document.createElement('a');
      a.href = this.input.value;
      this.button.disabled = !(a.host && a.host != window.location.host);

   }

}

const form = new Form("app");
```

It depends what you want to do with the form afterwards.

Comment: Quite sensible, thank you. About afterwards, I added input getter, to be able to use it in another class constructor like so https://github.com/askhat/table_generator/blob/master/src/index.js